# Maintaining state across dynamically generated pageBlockTables

Tags: visualforce, pageblocktable, wrapper-class

It's been a while, and I feel like I'm missing something simple/obvious but have been spinning my wheels for a while and can't find an answer.

The essence of my problem is that I cannot maintain the state of row column values in a pageBlockTable where those pageBlockTables are generated dynamically. The state is only maintained for the *last* table generated. I have illustrated the issue in the page/controller below and a screenshot for context:

**TestPage.page**

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true" controller="TestController">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Header">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Process" action="{!doNothing}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" collapsible="false" title="Location">
                <apex:repeat var="section" value="{!Sections}">
                    <h1>{!section}</h1>
                    <apex:variable var="wrappers" value="{!Sections[section]}"/>
                    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrappers}" var="wrapper" >
                        <apex:column breakBefore="true" colspan="1" >
                            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!wrapper.isSelected}" />
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column headerValue="Wrapper Title" >
                            <apex:inputText value="{!wrapper.title}" />
                        </apex:column>
                    </apex:pageBlockTable>
                </apex:repeat>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**TestController.cls**

```
public with sharing class TestController 
{
    public TestController() {}
    public PageReference doNothing()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public Map<String,List<Wrapper>> Sections
    {
        get 
        {
            if(Sections == null)
            {
                Sections =  new Map<String,List<Wrapper>>{'Section 1'=>new List<Wrapper>{new Wrapper('section 1, item 1'), new Wrapper('section 1, item 2')}, 'Section 2'=>new List<Wrapper>{new Wrapper('section 2, item 1'), new Wrapper('section 2, item 2')}};
            }
            return Sections;
        }
        set;
    }
    public class Wrapper
    {
        public Boolean isSelected {get;set;}
        public String title {get;set;}
        public Wrapper(String title)
        {
            this.title = title;
            this.isSelected = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Despite checking all boxes for both sections, after the Process button is clicked, only the last table has retained its state.

[image]

Does anyone have any bright ideas as to what I'm missing here or an explanation for this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a feeling it may have to do with the fact that you are declaring an `<apex:variable />` inside the repeater.  I changed the object model a little and that is no longer necessary.  This seems to do the trick.

**Controller:**

```
public with sharing class TestController 
{
    public TestController() {}
    public PageReference doNothing()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public List<Section> Sections
    {
        get 
        {
            if (Sections == null)
            {
                Sections = new List<Section>
                {
                    new Section('Section 1',
                            new List<Wrapper>{new Wrapper('section 1, item 1'), new Wrapper('section 1, item 2')}
                        ),
                    new Section('Section 2',
                            new List<Wrapper>{new Wrapper('section 2, item 1'), new Wrapper('section 2, item 2')}
                        )
                };
            }
            return Sections;
        }
        set;
    }

    public class Section
    {
        public String header {get;set;}
        public List<Wrapper> wrappers {get;set;}
        public Section(String header, List<Wrapper> wrappers)
        {
            this.header = header;
            this.wrappers = wrappers;
        }
    }

    public class Wrapper
    {
        public Boolean isSelected {get;set;}
        public String title {get;set;}
        public Wrapper(String title)
        {

            this.title = title;
            this.isSelected = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**VF Page:**

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true" controller="TestController">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Header">
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Process" action="{!doNothing}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" collapsible="false" title="Location">
                <apex:repeat var="section" value="{!Sections}">
                    <h1>{!section.header}</h1>
                    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!section.wrappers}" var="wrapper" >
                        <apex:column breakBefore="true" colspan="1" >
                            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!wrapper.isSelected}" />
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column headerValue="Wrapper Title" >
                            <apex:inputText value="{!wrapper.title}" />
                        </apex:column>
                    </apex:pageBlockTable>
                </apex:repeat>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Screenshot**

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Wow, I did not expect that to be the issue - thank you, I had been spinning my wheels for a while on that!